# Sunspot Solr Boost on text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr, solr-boost

I want to boost documents in the result based on any text field.

eg. consider following schema

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :body
    text :comments do
      comments.map { |comment| comment.body }
    end
    text :tags
    boolean :featured
  end
end
```

to boost on the Boolean field we can simple add a boost clause like this:

```
Post.search do
  fulltext '*:*' do
    boost(2.0){with(:featured, true)}
  end
end
```

I want to achieve boosting on text field, let's say I want to get all the post, but post tagged 'important' must come first, something like this:

```
Post.search do
  fulltext '*:*' do
    boost(2.0){fulltext 'important', fields: :tags}
  end
end
```

I know above code is not correct, but explains the required behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   Post.search do
      fulltext '*:*' do
         boost(2) { with(:tags).equal_to('important') }
      end
    end
```